# Differential operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

One define the operator $T$ as :$$T: = (I - {{{\partial ^2}} \over {\partial {x^2}}}):H_0^1(0,L) \cap {H^2}(0,L) \to {L^2}(0,L)
$$ let $f \in H_0^2(0,L) \cap {H^4}(0,L)$. What can we say about ${T^{ - 1}}{{{\partial ^4}f} \over {\partial {x^4}}}$ ?  In which space is it?

My attempt is as following : 
${T^{ - 1}}:{L^2}(0,L) \to H_0^1(0,L) \cap {H^2}(0,L)$  so ${{{\partial ^4}f} \over {\partial {x^4}}} \in {L^2}(0,L)$
So $${\left\| {{T^{ - 1}}{{{\partial ^4}f} \over {\partial {x^4}}}} \right\|_{{L^2}}} \le c{\left\| {{{{\partial ^2}f} \over {\partial {x^2}}}} \right\|_{{L^2}}}.
$$ Is this write ?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, $(1-D^2)^{-1}D^2$ is bounded on $L^2$ with operator norm $=1$. This is immediate from the fact that $-D^2\ge 0$ if you impose Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: @Christian Remling.Hello sir. have we  the same result here?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297354/spectral-decomposition-and-equivalance/2297599?noredirect=1#comment4727133_2297599